# VUE problem: reactive variables declared in <script setup> are reported undefined in created()

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm working on vue 3.2

the following codes **work well in dev environment**

`

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue"
let state = reactive({
    a:'',
    b:''
})
</setup>
```

```
export default
{

    created() {
         console.log(this.state)
    }
}
```

`

however, after npm run build, **in production environment, "this.state" comes out to be undefined**

thanks for help

I'v tried all resolutions in https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6282
none works

This project is an old massive one just upgraded, so there are many old codes using options API with a lot of "this.abcd" haha.
Also, It could be a great trouble to change this.xx into ref(xx) and xx.value = 'abc'
I'm wondering is there an alternative resolution, so that I can just decleare vars in composition API , and also use them in options API? thanks a lot

I'v found a related issue in https://lightrun.com/answers/vuejs-core-when-use-custom-v-model-with--script-setup--styleit-goes-well-in-dev-envbut-may-occur-errormo . and I also encountered this issue.

**the key point is different behaviour between dev and product** , so is it possible to make some config to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

`created` lifecycle is for options API, You don't need to define it in the composition API syntax with `setup` function, because `created` and `beforeCreated` lifecycles are replaced with `setup` function, So anything you want to execute in there you can directly execute it in the `setup` function.

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue"
let state = reactive({
    a:'',
    b:''
})

console.log(state)
</setup>
```

Comment: thanks for your answering. this project is an old massive one just upgraded, so there are many old codes using options API  with a lot of  "this.  ... " haha .   I'm wondering is there an alternative resolution, so that I can just decleare vars in composition API , and also use them in options API?  thanks a lot

Comment: @lhxu if it's a big app already, simplest solution is to keep using Options API. It's still totally viable as is and you don't need to refacto everything even if using Vue3.

Comment: That's a very good way continuely using Options API, however, vue 3.2 no longer supports visiting functions in the parent compenent, so defineExpose becomes an inevitable option. I was forced to move many declarations into composition API

Comment: @lhxu using `$parent` you mean? Because Options API is open by default. Not sure of all the specs of Composition API tho.